# Get username Passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, server, passport.js

I am a beginner and I have simple node application that use passport js.

Everything works but I want to get username here

```
app.get('/', checkLogged, (req, res) => {

   res.render('index', {name: username});

});
```

Full project here https://github.com/aruzo1/passport

Can anybody help me?
There is way to do this?

Ps. This database is temporary

**app.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
    require('dotenv').config();
}

const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
      bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
      passport = require('passport'),
      initializePassport = require('./passport-config'),
      flash = require('express-flash'),
      session = require('express-session'),
      methodOverride = require('method-override'),
      users = []

initializePassport(passport,
     email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
     id => users.find(user =>  user.id === id)
);
require('ejs');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.get('/', checkLogged, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {name: ""});
});

app.get('/login', checkNotLogged, (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {});
});

app.get('/register', checkNotLogged, (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {});
});

app.post('/register', checkNotLogged, async (req, res) => {
    try{
        hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        users.push({
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        });
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
    catch{
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
});

app.post('/login', checkNotLogged, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/login')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('serwer wystartowal')
});

function checkLogged(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}

function checkNotLogged(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}
```

**passport-config.js**

```
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
      bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById){
    const authentitaceUser = async (email, password, done) =>{
        const user = getUserByEmail(email);
        if (user == null){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'no user with that email'});
        };

        try{
            if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
                return done(null, user)
            }
            else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'wrong password'})
            }
        } 
        catch(e){
            return done(e)
        }
    };

    passport.use(new localStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email'
    }, authentitaceUser));

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        return done(null, user.id)
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done(null, getUserById(id))
    });
};

module.exports = initialize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.render('index', {name: req.user.username })`

Should do the trick, as long the authentication itself was a success and your user has a 'username' field. Otherwise, `req.user.username` should throw an error;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using persistent sessions too - you should be able to grab user info from req.user and include it in your response...

```
app.get('/', checkLogged, (req, res) => {

   res.send(req.user);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In passport.js when it verifies that user is logged in then the passport.js automatically set the logged-in user info to the res object.So it means whenever user send the request then the req object already having the user info.Here is the function whichdoing this:

```
  passport.setAuthenticatedUser=(req,res,next)=>{
if(req.isAuthenticated())
{
    res.locals.user=req.user;
}
next();
```

}

So in your case when user logged in at that time passport automatically set the user info to every res object.So when any request is coming in that request there is already an user info is present.

So that;s why you need write:

```
  res.render('index', {name: req.user.username })
```

instead of writing:

```
    res.render('index', {name: username});
```